# What HDMI cable supports PC display stand-by?

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi, desktop-computer

I had my LG display connected to the PC via HDMI for about a year and the display always went to sleep when I shut down my PC and automatically went back on when I turned on the PC.
Now I have a new desk and was forced to use a slightly longer HDMI cable (3m vs. 1.8m). With this new cable, when the PC turns off, the display tells me that there is no input signal for about a minute and then turns off completely (status light is off instead of blinking as it was previously with the other cable). When I turn on the PC, I also have to manually turn on the display.
Just to be sure, I checked with the old HDMI cable and the old behavior came back, so it's definitely the cable and not something else.

If I have to buy a new HDMI cable, what do I have to look for so that the display turns off and on together with the PC?

Comment: I have my doubts the behavior is caused by the cable itself.

Comment: You told us nothing about the current HDMI cables you have.  Hard to do research on possible causes for that reason.

Comment: Sorry, what information do you need? Unfortunately, I have no idea what HDMI version they support. They are both cables I had laying around.

Comment: Just re-checked. The old cable has "HIGH SPEED HDMI CABLE WITH ETHERNET" printed on it, along with "80 °C 30V". The new cable is absolutely blank. It is also somewhat thinner than the old cable.

Comment: @smares in that case the old cable is a new cable and the new cable is an old cable =]

Comment: @Ramhound I'm by no means an hdmi cable expert, but I've had somewhat of a similar experience.   To me the hdmi cables that say "with Ethernet" have different behaviors than those that don't.   I've yet to see a setup that actually implements Ethernet over hdmi tho, it's somewhat confusing.

Comment: I've got three cables here one that seems to support display standby but unfortunately has stopped being reliable and two that are reliable but  don't support standby.  It's a good mystery.   I'll try an HDMI 2 cable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply bought a new HDMI 2.0 compatible cable and everything works as intended now. Wondering what kind of HDMI feature my other cable didn't support.